# replacing nil value with other customized value

Tags: ios, swift, syntax

I am using a keychain wrapper written in Swift. 
When value is nil, this wrapper I'm using automatically saves data as "nil" instead of saving as an actual nil value.

```
For ex, ["last_name" : "nil"].
```

In one of my label in my iOS app, I'm returning last_name value.
It bothers me that a text in label is saying "nil" when there supposed to be nothing.

I remember in Swift that there is a syntax like A ?? B which puts B instead if A is not valid. But I cannot remember it right now. 
In my app, I want to something like below:

```
if the value I'm looking for is nil, then input "" instead of "nil"
If keychain["last_name"] == nil ?? ""
```

I know this is a horrible explanation but this is all I could come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`??` is the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72). It is used for unwrapping optionals — `a ?? b` is shorthand for `a != nil ? a! : b`.

You probably want to use the ternary operator instead. You could even combine them like this:

```
let lastName = keychain["last_name"] == "nil" ? "" : (keychain["last_name"] ?? "")
```

That said, it might be easier to just filter out these responses immediately after getting the keychain instead of checking every time:

```
var keychain = ["first_name" : "aaron", "last_name" : "nil"]

keychain.forEach { if $0.1 == "nil" { keychain.removeValueForKey($0.0) } }

print(keychain)  //["first_name": "aaron"]
```

The `$0` is a *shorthand argument name*. Here's the long form version of the same code:

```
keychain.forEach { (key, value) -> () in
    if value == "nil" {
        keychain.removeValueForKey(key)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Solved it :) One quick question. Do you mind giving me further explanation on $0.1? Would it cause a problem if I do $0.0?

Comment: `$0` is a key-value pair passed into the `forEach` closure. `$0.0` represents the key (like `first_name`), and `$0.1` is the value (like `aaron`).

Comment: Thank you a lot Aaron :) It would be super nice if you can tell me what this kind of syntax is called so I can look it up in Apple's document.

Comment: @Kahsn `$0` is a "Shorthand Argument Name" — described in the [closures docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).